# How to transform some column when export data form hive?

Tags: java, hadoop, export, hive

For example, I have some data like: `a|b|c|/r/n` and I want to transform column `'/r/n'` to  `' '`. Can Hive do it? When exporting from Hive, some `null` column  will be export to `/r/n`, so I want to change `'/r/n'` to `''`. I have many data to be be exported, therefore I want to do it in Hive.

Answer (score 0):

[If](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions) column4 equals to '/r/n' replace with '' like below.

```
 select if(col4='/r/n','',col4) from table1
```

Comment: i don't know which column will do this transform. so is there other way to do this? otherwise i will do select if(col1...) if(col2..) if(col3...) ... from table. i want to see  source code of hive ,try to change some code for make '/r/n' to ''.can you have   advise